# Would long-polling be a good substitute for websockets in this case?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am attempting to develop a 'boardgame' sort-of application, for simplicity sake let's think of monopoly as everybody is familiar with that one. I've read a bit about long-polling and it's implications and this got me confused as it is stated that you need to utilize a framework for it (such as socket.io) anyway, which then uses websockets and such.

1. **Is it possible to avoid this?**
   I understand that websockets are much better then an ajax request sitting and waiting for a response, but reading up on them made me a bit "scared" of how to implement such a thing. I am not too familiar with node.js (though I'd love to be) mainly because from what I understand it has low hosting support by the providers and is "overly complex to use" or whatnot.
2. **Generally speaking, since we are talking about a boardgame** I am not certain that I really need websockets to use realtime client-server communication, because mainly, boardgames are not that intensive on the simultaneous actions and I do not think there would be too many changes to communicate in a short timeframe. I might not be understanding this whole thing correctly so **correct me if I am wrong** but if the game is slow paced, such as board games usually are, a simple AJAX request should suffice, no? If only I could keep it open in-definitively.
3. **Would it be considered** "good practice" to avoid websockets in this case, I mean sure using them is just better then using other things but, comparatively gains are minimal in this case (unless I am not seeing a bigger picture here) for the effort needed to implement it.

P.S. If somebody can recommend a good starting point to how to implement websockets for a simple app such as this one, or direct me to a good "learning material" for node.js that would be awesome as well. I ideally would love to write my backend in js instead of PHP, but I got no clue where to start. I have WAMP running at my machine to test things, IDK how I'd setup node to work on that, or at all.

Comment: 1. NodeJS is most definitely not overly complex to use, and if your host doesn't let you install Node, I suggest changing hosts because that's a bad host. Digital Ocean has cheap, root controlled droplets for very cheap. 2. Don't avoid something because you're scared -- Dive into it and own it!

Comment: PHP also has support for websockets: http://socketo.me/

Comment: Would you say that websockets are 'required/needed' in this case, we are talking about a board game here, which generally doesn't require much real-time, as it is turn based, so I am under the impression that long-polling would suffice.

Comment: There are WebSocket libraries for pretty much any language, and implementation is not complex at all. (From my own personal background, I recommend you take a look at the WAMP protocol (http://wamp-proto.org) and its implementations, e.g. Crossbar.io (http://crossbar.io) as a router, which offers communication patterns on top of WebSocket)

Comment: I will read upon it a bit, though from the previous comments I've sort of been pushed towords node, and JS is the language I am most comfortable around, so it would make sense. Still need to find a good resource to learn it, but am getting there, slowly. Time is scarce between work and life to get studying going as well.